# Unable to flatten array of DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, apache-spark-sql

I have an array of `DataFrame`s that I obtain by using `randomSplit()` in this manner:

`val folds = df.randomSplit(Array.fill(5)(1.0/5))   //Array[Dataset[Row]]`

I'll be iterating over folds using a for loop, where I will be dropping the `i`th entry inside `folds` and store it separately. Then I will be using all the others as another `DataFrame` as in my code below:

```
    val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("xyz")
    val folds = df.randomSplit(Array.fill(5)(1.0/5))

    for (i <- folds.indices) {
        var ts = folds
        val testSet = ts(i)
        ts = ts.drop(i)

        var trainSet = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], testSet.schema)

        for (j <- ts.indices) {
            trainSet = trainSet.union(ts(j))
        }
    }
```

While this does serve my purpose, I was also trying another approach where I would still separate `folds` into `ts` and `testSet`, and then use the `flatten` function for the remaining inside `ts` to create another `DataFrame` using something like this:

```
    val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("xyz")
    val folds = df.randomSplit(Array.fill(5)(1.0/5))

    for (i <- folds.indices) {
        var ts = folds
        val testSet = ts(i)
        ts = ts.drop(i)

        var trainSet = ts.flatten
    }
```

But at the initialization of the `trainSet` line, I get an error that: `No Implicits Found for parameter asTrav: Dataset[Row] => Traversable[U_]`. I have also done `import spark.implicits._` after initializing the SparkSession.

My end goal with the creation of `trainSet` after `flatten` is to retrieve a `DataFrame` created after joining (union) the other `Dataset[Row]`s inside `ts`. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I'm using Spark 2.4.5 with Scala 2.11.12

EDIT 1: Added how I read the Dataframe

Comment: can you post please the structure of `testSet`? I mean how did you declare and what is a type of it?

Comment: Well, I did a simple `spark.read.csv`, then did a `randomSplit` over that, then selected a value from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced that `for` loop with a simple reduce:

```
val trainSet = ts.reduce((a,b) => a.union(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your intention here but instead of using mutable variables and flattening you can do recursive iteration like this:

```scala
  val folds = df.randomSplit(Array.fill(5)(1.0/5))   //Array[Dataset[Row]]
  val testSet = spark.createDataFrame(Seq.empty)
  val trainSet = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], testSet.schema)

  go(folds, Array.empty)

  def go(items: Array[Dataset[Row]], result: Array[Dataset[Row]]): Array[Dataset[Row]] = items match {
    case arr @ Array(_, _*) =>
      val res = arr.map { t =>
        trainSet.union(t)
      }
      go(arr.tail, result ++ res)
    case Array() => result
  }
```

As I have seen the use case of `testSet`, there is no usage of it in the method body

Comment: My intention is to separate `folds` into a `testSet` and a `trainSet`. I have to do this step 5 times (that's why a `for` loop). While iterating over the loop, I will always be creating a `testSet` and a `trainSet`. The reason why you don't see any usage of `testSet` is because I first have to split `folds` successfully, only then I can use it. Rest assured, I will need both of them.